# Determining moment and accelerations of blocks connected through rope and pulley

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, momentum, acceleration, string

A pulley, of radius $r$, mass $m$ and moment of inertia $I$ with respect to the axis orthogonal to the vertical plane where the pulley is positioned and going through its center, two masses are hanging, $m_{1}$ and $m_{2}$, connected via a non-extensible rope. $m_{1} > m_{2}$. Determine:

- the acceleration of the both masses
- the tension of $T_{1}$ and $T_{2}$
- the binding reaction (for lack of knowledge of a better term in English) on the pulley's axis

We can assume the rope doesn't slip and there is no friction on the pulley's axis.

[image: Problem representation]

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to choose the $x$, $y$ and $z$, the frame of reference; in particular the $z$ axis: is there a specific rule I can follow to choose whether it points inwards or outwards?

How would you determine the pulley's moments (or momentums... momenta?), their signs and accelerations of the masses?

Comment: This is one of the simplest problems. Why are you having a hard time figuring out axis and frame of reference. Is this your first question

Comment: Not at all – I'm having a very hard time figuring out why the $z$ axis points outwards or inwards. Does it depend on whether the pulley rotates clockwise or counterclockwise? Is there any specific rule? I've seen my prof sending classmates home instantly due to how the axis is chosen, he wants to specifically know why. And I don't know.

Comment: X, y and z axis follow right hand rule. So z depends on x and y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Z axis points wherever you want. Coordinate system is something we invented and it is up to you where you place it. It is advised that it is placed n such way that calculations are easier. The thing is to be consistent with it. Moreover the pulleys moment of inertia is stated so u do not have to determine it.

Answer (score 1):

This is the free body diagram

[image]

to solve the problem you need 5 equations for the 5 unknowns. You have to take the right sign to obtain the torque from the tensions , and the right sign to obtain the rolling conditions.

The results for the mass accelerations tell you if your chose the right sign for $z_1,z_2$